# The loop in my R function appears to be running twice

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I need to add rows to a data frame. I have many files with many rows so I have converted the code to a function. When I go through each element of the code it works fine. When I wrap everything in a function each row from my first loop gets added twice.

My code looks for a string (xx or x). If xx is present is replaces the xx with numbers 00-99 (one row for each number) and 0-9. If x is present it replaces it with number 0-9.

#### Create DF

```
a <- c("1.x", "2.xx", "3.1")
b <- c("single", "double", "nothing")
df <- data.frame(a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df) <- c("code", "desc")
```

#### My dataframe

```
 code    desc
1  1.x  single
2 2.xx  double
3  3.1 nothing
```

#### My function

```
newdf <- function(df){

    # If I run through my code chunk by chunk it works as I want it.

    df$expanded <- 0 # a variable to let me know if the loop was run on the row

    emp <- function(){ # This function creates empty vectors for my loop
        assign("codes", c(), envir = .GlobalEnv)
        assign("desc", c(), envir = .GlobalEnv)
        assign("expanded", c(), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }

    emp()

    # I want to expand xx with numbers 00 - 99 and 0 - 9. 
    #Note: 2.0 is different than 2.00

    # Identifies the rows to be expanded    
    xd <- grep("xx", df$code)

    # I used chr vs. numeric so I wouldn't lose the trailing zero
    # Create a vector to loop through
    tens <- formatC(c(0:99)); tens <- tens[11:100]
    ones <- c("00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09")
    single <- as.character(c(0:9))
    exp <- c(single, ones, tens)

    # This loop appears to run twice when I run the function: newdf(df) 
    # Each row is there twice: 2.00, 2.00, 2.01 2.01... 
    # It runs as I want it to if I just highlight the code. 

    for (i in xd){
        for (n in exp) {
            codes <- c(codes, gsub("xx", n, df$code[i])) #expanding the number
            desc <- c(desc, df$desc[i])  # repeating the description
            expanded <- c(expanded, 1) # assigning 1 to indicated the row has been expanded
        }
    }

    # Binds the df with the new expansion
    df <- df[-xd, ]
    df <- rbind(as.matrix(df),cbind(codes,desc,expanded))
    df <- as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


    # Empties the vector to begin another expansion
    emp()
    xs <- grep("x", df$code) # This is for the single digit expansion

    # Expands the single digits. This part of the code works fine inside the function.
    for (i in xs){
        for (n in 0:9) {
            codes <- c(codes, gsub("x", n, df$code[i]))
            desc <- c(desc, df$desc[i])
            expanded <- c(expanded, 1)
        }
    }

    df <- df[-xs,]
    df <- rbind(as.matrix(df), cbind(codes,desc,expanded))
    df <- as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    assign("out", df, envir = .GlobalEnv) # This is how I view my dataframe after I run the function.
}
```

### Calling my function

```
newdf(df)
```

Comment: There are a lot of issues with your code. The first things that jump out at me are that you use `assign("foo", bar, envir = .GlobalEnv)`, which is almost never a good idea in a function.

Comment: Right, you should clear `codes`, `desc` and `expanded` within your function. The variables you are assigning in your loops are local to the function, they are not the global variables you clear in `emp()`.

Comment: You should also probably read about vectorisation and the problems with growing objects. For example, see https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf or http://adv-r.had.co.nz/

Comment: Thank you. I removed the emp() and just used ```codes <- c()``` before each loop and it worked. The vectors must not have emptied prior to running the second loop, which explains why everything was doubled.